# ASP Classic Active Directory Autologin without Popup

Tags: iis, asp-classic, active-directory

There are similar questions to this out there, but they are either unanswered or about ASP.Net.

My scenario is this:
I would like, when users hit an internal site (ASP Classic, IIS 6, windows server 2003), it to autologin and work out who they are, based on their Active Directory record WITHOUT a popup asking them to input their username and password. Using Anonymous Auth within IIS means that LOGON_USER outputs the Administrator user. Turning anonymous off means I get the popup.

As they have already logged into windows, is there a way for it to work out who they are, and not require them to input a username and password again.

I have got the AD integration within ASP cracked. Just need to stop it from asking for a Username and Password.

Thanks in advance,
James

Comment: Duplicate post: http://serverfault.com/q/327110/494

Comment: As mentioned in that post, it was because no-one had answered here! "There are similar question to this on stack overflow and I have pretty much posted the same question there, with no responses."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the request.ServerVariables collection, there is an AUTH_USER item that should be filled for authenticated users:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210125013535/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/servervariables.asp

To have classic ASP log in as a different user, you need an external COM object.
There is an example online that has some VB6 code you can compile into an activex COM object and call from classic ASP to log on as a different user (and log off again):

http://www.iisfaq.com/Default.aspx?tabid=2947

When logged in, your asp process will run under the logged in users name, and no longer under the user configured in IIS.

With these two bits of info, you should be able to work out if a user is logged in, and if not, automatically log them in under an account using ASP. The popup will no longer show up.

Hope this helps,

Erik

-edit- sorry, I just realise I may have misunderstood your question... authentication should be handled by IIS when your users are logged into Windows and "Integrated Windows authentication" is checked in the IIS setting under "directory security". Have you tried checking BOTH this checkbox AND anonymous access, but then denying READ access on your internal websites' folders for IUSR_[machinename]?
That should prevent anonymous users from accessing, and allow Windows users to pass.
It's propaply easiest to test this on a subfolder of one of your internal sites first, before messing with rights in the root of a site.

Answer (score 1):

This was very helpful to me. The reason I found specifically that it wasn't working for me is that there is a "." in the domain name. That makes the site not be treated as an intranet site.

Answer (score 0):

This is down to the browser.  What you want is for the browser to attempt to logon using the current user credentials.  In IE this the default behaviour for sites it identified as being in the "Intranet Zone".  So one approach to this to use a Group policy to ensure machines in the domain have the internal websites added to all the client machines Intranet site list.

Other browsers also have a mechanism to list sites to which the current user credentials may be used to satisfy a logon challange from a server.